# deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

Why am I getting this warning and how to fix it? Essentially, I want to convert a video to a jpg every 4th frame with the same resolution as original video.

```
[jalal@goku vid2]$ ffmpeg -i debate_vid2.mov -r 0.25 images_%08d.jpg
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'debate_vid2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2017-03-10 02:45:46
  Duration: 01:36:50.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 785 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-03-10 02:45:46
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 334x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 167:180], 685 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-03-10 02:45:46
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
[swscaler @ 0x1bb4240] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'images_%08d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 334x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 167:180], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.25 fps, 0.25 tbn, 0.25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-03-10 02:45:46
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1454 fps= 25 q=1.6 Lsize=N/A time=01:36:56.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=172847    
video:28470kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[jalal@goku vid2]$
```

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=deprecated+pixel+format+used+ffmpeg

Comment: @Hannu yeah thanks mate, the first result for that is... this topic.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are just converting videos using `ffmpeg`, this is just a warning, not an error, and nothing to worry about.

You can safely ignore the message when using ffmpeg from the command-line, and you don't have to fix anything.

**Background:**

The warning occurs when converting from a `yuv420p` source to JPEG, which makes ffmpeg choose `yuvj420p` as output format. That format is required for writing files with the `mjpeg` encoder.

These two pixel formats have different color ranges: `yuv420p` is from 16–235, which is "limited range" (also called  "MPEG" range); `yuvj420p` defaults to 0–255, which is "full range".

This difference in color formats (which were selected automatically) makes ffmpeg trigger that specific warning message, telling you to make sure you set the color range correctly.

The warning is primarly meant for developers who use FFmpeg as a library in their own code ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067722/swscaler-warning-deprecated-pixel-format-used/23216860)). See also the comments on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1543502/48078). The specific deprecation is [listed here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html#a9a8e335cf3be472042bc9f0cf80cd4c5aef61d7a65003ef618420f618294107b0):

> planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P and setting color_range

Comment: same issue. and for me `ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers`

Comment: Ignoring a warning isn't a fix

Comment: @KonradLinkowski What are you suggesting? As an end user, it won't have any effect. If you think the message can be improved in terms of clarity, please send a patch to `ffmpeg-devel`. As far as I can tell it was introduced to [fix a different bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3242) 8 years ago and hasn't been touched since.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski FWIW I proposed a patch: https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20211124115738.84650-1-werner.robitza@gmail.com/

Comment: @slhck Thanks for submitting the patch. Is this now integrated into the latest versions of FFmpeg?

Comment: @HashimAziz No, I never got feedback on it.

Comment: @slhck That's annoying, I assumed because the checks had passed it would be a done deal, there's no real reason why this shouldn't go ahead. I can't program well enough to directly contribute but if I can otherwise help in getting the patch applied, let me know.

Comment: @HashimAziz You're right. It's not a technical issue, more of an organizational one. There's probably not much you can do other than reply to the thread on ffmpeg-devel and ask what's up with the patch.

Comment: The warning was introduced [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/5bccb2d0965a66c132798c748b64a5025a5636a9) actually. And [AFAICT](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/af0e66216952c170c0acb28398f1c543b6f3d8d2) and [AFAIU](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8455#comment:27) the plan was always more or less to have the JPEG formats removed. It's just that you need manpower for that, and fix all the other "surrounding" [bugs](https://superuser.com/questions/1543502/ffmpeg-encoding-requested-yuv420p-but-got-yuvj420p#comment2345801_1543502).

Comment: Just a note saying this is still not 'fixed', 5 years later...

Comment: @slhck hi, by saying `the former is from 16–235`, the former is `yuv420p`, the latter is `yuvj420p` right?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the accepted answer, it's just a warning which can be ignored.

If processing many files, you can reduce the output of `ffmpeg` using the `-loglevel` option [described here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options). Setting it to `-loglevel error` will suppress these and other warnings.

So, using your example, something like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i debate_vid2.mov -r 0.25 images_%08d.jpg
```