# ffmpeg encoding requested yuv420p but got yuvj420p

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, ubuntu-18.04, h.264, video-codecs

When I encode with ffmpeg on Ubuntu 18, the default encoder `h264 (libx264)` uses by default the pixel format `yuvj420p`.
But https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h_source.html says that AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P is "full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P and setting color_range."
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 also recommends "use -vf format=yuv420p (or the alias -pix_fmt yuv420p)."

No "j."  Let's try that.

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -movflags +faststart -crf 18 -preset slower \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-vf "scale=in_range=mpeg:out_range=full" \
-color_range 2 out.mov`

That command reports: `encoder : Lavf57.83.100`,... `Video: h264 (libx264) ... yuv420p(pc, progressive)`.

But `ffplay out.mov` complains "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly."
`ffprobe out.mov` agrees that the result is `yuvj420p`, not my requested `yuv420p`.

Even `diff` reports that the result is bitwise identical to that from a command that omits the options for pix_fmt, vf, and color_range.

`ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264` reports `Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p ...`.

**What's the correct way to encode yuv420p with full color range?**

`ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
configuration: ... --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 ... --enable-libx264`

Comment: At this time, yuv 4:2:0 with full range is signaled as `yuvj420p` upon decoding.  Deprecated but not removed yet, so not a concern.

Comment: First off, you can jut ignore the warning. Its form code that needs to be updated, but hasn't yet. Second `-vf "scale=in_range=mpeg:out_range=full"` is setting the range to full. Which is `yuvj420p`

Comment: If the deprecation is a side effect of the identical signatures, in libavutil/pixdesc.c's av_pix_fmt_descriptors[], of AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P and AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P, then I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: That is just a bug, and that warning just notifies us devs that it is a bug, just like with any jpeg (jpeg decoder does not support new api yet) or with jpeg inside flac or other music with cover art.