# DSLR as webcam, low fps

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam

I'm trying to use my Canon DSLR as a webcam.

This is the command I have running in the background, in order to get a `/dev/video0`:

```
$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

This works, kind of, but I get fps between 4 and 5. I'd like to get better than that, I'm ok to sacrifice image resolution.

Here is the output of the command above:

```
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mjpeg @ 0x55bae133d9c0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x640, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x55bae138a4e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, v4l2, to '/dev/video0':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y42B / 0x42323459), yuv422p, 960x640, q=2-31, 245760 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 rawvideo
frame=  719 fps=4.5 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:28.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.182x
```

I've searched for the warnings, but one seemed [expected and ok](https://superuser.com/questions/1273920/deprecated-pixel-format-used-make-sure-you-did-set-range-correctly/1273941), not sure about `Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25`.

Is it possible to get better fps? the resolution seems to be 960x640, I think it's physically possible even on USB2?

I *think* that the issue is not in ffmpeg, rather before that, because letting gphoto2 output to the terminal, I feels that updates are also about 4 per second. Just a feel though.

Comment: I'm a Nikon shooter, so no experience with Canon, but I remembered seeing this only yesterday, new official Canon web-cam app - https://uk.pcmag.com/how-to-work-from-home/126750/how-to-use-your-canon-dslr-as-a-webcam might be worth a look.

Comment: Wow, that's timely. Although, I'm on Ubuntu, my camera is from 2014, "Zoom and Skype aren't supported" :)

Comment: Ah, shame. I actually have a similar issue on Mac, but I just gave up & bought a webcam to do webcam… keep the camera for 'proper' jobs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An update of `libgphoto2` (not from `apt`, from the source on github) got the fps to 12. Branch `master` has even higher, but is less stable yet.